# Typekit integration not working with ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, typekit

I am trying to load a font with the typekit api.

Using the following code it works fine in HTML/JS:

```
    <!-- Typekit -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/API-KEY.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

In Ruby, I use this:

```
      %script{src: "http://use.typekit.net/API-KEY.js", type: "text/javascript"}
  :javascript
    try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
```

But the font is not loading properly

What is the pb?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should do:

1. Inspect your generated HTML source, and see if it looks right
2. Look at your javascript error console for hints

Also, no reason to use `%script` directly, the [`javascript_include_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) helper is here for you!

Comment: The generated HTML looks like the one I have on my HTML file with no ruby and my javascript console does show anything

Comment: Remove the `try/catch` block around the `Typekit.load()` code, you're hiding any errors that may be trying to get out.